# Attach and detach database using VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using around 300 SQL Server databases where memory is about 119 GB. Due to memory issues, I have tried to detach and attach a database as required.

Code to attach a database:

```vb
Private Sub AttachDB()
    Dim VQ101 As String
    VQ101 = "CREATE DATABASE [USERRIS] ON  "
    VQ101 &= " ( FILENAME = N'D:\ASSETS\USERRIS.mdf' ), "
    VQ101 &= " ( FILENAME = N'D:\ASSETS\USERRIS_log.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH"
    Dim StrConState As String = "server=' " + MySerName + " ';Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim ViewQuery As String = VQ101
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(StrConState)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(ViewQuery)
            cmd.Connection = connection
            connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Code to detach a database:

```vb
Private Sub DetatchDB()
    Dim VQ101 As String
    VQ101 = "EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'USERRIS'"
    Dim StrConState As String = "server=' " + MySerName + " ';Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim ViewQuery As String = VQ101
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(StrConState)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(ViewQuery)
            cmd.Connection = connection
            connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Screenshot of the error I get:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Gj7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Gj7.png)

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; it is considered quite rude.

Comment: Usually, you need to set single user to the database, like described in this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/alter-database-set-single_user-statement-in-sql-server/ But your whole premise is a bit strange :/ A new 1TB SSD cost like 100 $. If you're talking about RAM, a database doesn't take memory, only queries to it do. You can change the maximum amount of RAM that sql server can use by: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I feel like something has gone a little wrong as well if you have *3000* databases on a single instance.

Comment: Its not about adding SSD. Its only about attaching only required database and detaching the same after operation done. It will be a added security for any unauthorised access.

Comment: Further to @siggemannen 's comment, the requirement is also [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#obtaining-exclusive-access).

Comment: *"Its only about attaching only required database and detaching the same after operation done. It will be a added security for any unauthorised access."* Now this sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Yes all the databases are in Single Instance

Comment: Add `ALTER DATABASE USERRIS SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;` before the `sp_detach_db` statement.

Comment: Also you might want to add `@skipchecks = 'true'` to speed up the detach.

Comment: " It will be a added security for any unauthorised access. ". So will shutting down the server. No one detaches databases for security purposes. You mention memory issues, which is probably your real reason, but I agree with @ThomA this is an XY problem.

Comment: The statements 1. Alter ....... 2. Exec ..... works good in Sql Server Configuration Manager. But when executed through vb.net code the database is turning to SINGLE_USER mode, but showing "Database in Use" when Detach statement executes.

Comment: Are you doing those two statements in the same batch?

Comment: In two different functions. First function will set Database in SINGLE_User mode. and Second will detach

Comment: @Rajesh,add the command before the `EXEC` in the same batch as I instructed.